# Same scroll speed across devices with different DPI

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser-based-games, side-scroller

I am creating a simple game in JS, something like the flappy bird :)
For pipe scroll, I am using a linear tween.

I noticed that the speed of the pipes are different across different smartphone screens, so 
the game has different difficulty.

I observed that this has to do with different screen sizes and different pixels densities.

What I did is I defined a duration per pixel, which is multiplied by the number of pixels the screen has.
The duration per pixel, `pixel_duration` is constant.

So basically:

```
tween_duration = number_of_horizontal_pixels * pixel_duration
```

But this gives same speed in different sized browser windows on the (same) computer screen.
If I use this approach on some device that has higher pixel density, the pipes will move slower,
because there are more pixels, so this `tween_duration` value gets larger, so tween gets slower.

Then I learned of the `devicePixel` ratio value which can be used. So I try to factor this in the equation:

```
tween_duration = number_of_horizontal_pixels * pixel_duration / devicePixelRatio
```

This `devicePixelRatio` is higher as screen DPI's goes higher and should solve my problem according to the docs, right?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

However, this only helps a bit. There is still a noticable speed difference.

Why is this not working, and how can I get the same scroll speed across devices in JS (in browser window) - perhaps some other approach would do?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606369/4934560

Comment: Are you sure this is a density problem and not something that could be solved with `deltaTime` ? I'm asking because I've encountered a similar issue in the past using javascript and Pixi.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to go as deep as to device pixel ratio?

If it's a browser-based game, then you

1. have access to the [viewport-percentage units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) like `vmin`, `vmax`, `vw`, `vh`. Why not use them?
2. If you are using canvas to render output, why not stylize it to fit entire viewport while maintaining the same pixel dimension?
3. Why not use `meta` tag to adjust the size of your page in logical pixels for mobile devices?

Comment: Yes, this is a browser-based game, but all I can use is the canvas. So any features that canvas supports are ok.
I cannot create/modify anything else outside given canvas object.